# failed_jobs table in laravel pgsql

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, heroku, queue

I'm using database queuing in laravel ( my database in pgsql) , and the jobs always fails after go to failed_jobs table after 3 attempts, how to check the failure reason?

The project is using heroku and here is hte procfile

```
worker: php artisan queue:listen --tries 3
```

the records in failed jobs contains connection = database and queue = default.

here is my settings

```
'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'expire' => 120,
    ],
 'failed' => [
    'database' => 'pgsql', 'table' => 'failed_jobs',
],
```

how to check the reason of failure ?

Answer (score 0):

You should verify your logs (by default in `storage/logs`) - for example some exceptions may be thrown and that's why job hasn't been successfully finished

Answer (score -1):

You can find the errors in 'exception' column of failed_jobs table.